# Javascript Client for FOSOAuthServerBundle

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, fosoauthserverbundle, hello.js

I have some difficulties to get the authentification workflow working. I tried JSO https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso/blob/master/README-getting-started.md

here is my test code (ignore the login fields)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/jso/build/jso.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="login" method="post">
    login: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
    password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
<input type="button" value="Get Token" id="get_token">
<input type="button" value="Clear Token" id="clear_token">
<input type="button" value="Dump" id="dump">
<input type="button" value="Fetch" id="fetch">
<input type="button" value="Callback" id="callback">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jso;
        $.getJSON('parameters.json', function (data) {
            jso = new JSO({
                providerID: "movieApp",
                client_id: data['backend-api']['client_id'],
                redirect_uri: window.location.href,
                authorization: "http://" + data['backend-api']['host'] + "/oauth/v2/auth",
                scopes: {request: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]}
            });
            console.log(data['backend-api']['host']);
        });

        JSO.enablejQuery($);

        $('#get_token').click(function () {
            jso.getToken(function (token) {

                console.log("I got the token: ", token);

            });
        });
        $('#clear_token').click(function () {
            jso.wipeTokens()
        });
        $('#callback').click(function () {
            jso.callback()
        });
        $('#dump').click(function () {
            alert(jso.dump());
        });
        $('#fetch').click(function () {
            jso.ajax({
                url: "http://movie-app.localhost/app_dev.php/showtimes/2014-09-27",
                dataType: 'json',
                //crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Response (google):");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if I've got the workflow right as every time I want to fetch data from the URL I need to give the authorisation to use api.
I thought the first time I try to fetch data I need to authorize, but then I use token but it doesn't work this way with my code.
Can somebody please give a good example how to use JSO, Hello.js or any other Javascript Client Code with FosOAuthServerBundle